# Change Drawer Icon of Drawer Widget being returned from an external Class

Tags: flutter, dart, navigation-drawer

I'm trying to change the icon and color of my drawer widget in Dart. I've found ways of doing it but none that apply to my scenario. My custom drawer widget is being returned from another class and so I can't change the leading icon in the home class where the app bar is or it will replace my current drawer. I won't show all the code because I don't believe it would be necessary. Any help would be appreciated.

My Current drawer and method of calling it:

**Drawer class:**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:new_app/Users.dart';
import '../main.dart';

class MainDrawer extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Drawer(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            width: double.infinity,
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
            color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
            child: Center(
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Container(
```

**Menu Class/ home page:**

```
import 'screens/drawer_main.dart';

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
        onWillPop: () {
          return new Future(() => false);
        },
        child: Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey[900],
          appBar: AppBar(
            //backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey[900],
            backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
            automaticallyImplyLeading: true,
            title: Text(
              "Home Page",
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
            ),

            actions: <Widget>[
              //Profile Pic
              IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.circle, color: Colors.white),
                tooltip: 'Comment Icon',
                onPressed: () {},
              ),
              MainPopUp(), //IconButton
            ],
            //IconButton
            brightness: Brightness.dark,
          ),
          //Current Method of Calling the Drawer: 
          drawer: MainDrawer(),
          body: Center(
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a leading inside `AppBar()` and open drawer programatically.

```
AppBar(
  leading: InkWell(
      child: Icon(
      //your preferred icon
      Icons.camera
     ),
     onTap: () {
         Scaffold.of(context).openDrawer();
     },
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Add the leading property in the App Bar and then call the Drawer Widget Programmatically.

```
Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey[900],
      appBar: AppBar(
        //backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey[900],
         leading: Builder(
          builder: (context) => IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.menu_rounded),
            onPressed: () => Scaffold.of(context).openDrawer(),
          ),
        ),
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        automaticallyImplyLeading: true,
        title: Text(
          "Home Page",
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
        ),

        actions: <Widget>[
          //Profile Pic
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.circle, color: Colors.white),
            tooltip: 'Comment Icon',
            onPressed: () {},
          ),
          MainPopUp(), //IconButton
        ],
        //IconButton
        brightness: Brightness.dark,
      ),
      //Current Method of Calling the Drawer: 
      drawer: MainDrawer(),
```